# How to get some stlyed item from Holo Dark theme to older android versions?

Tags: android

I would like to get the look of an EditText just like the way it is in Holo Dark theme.
Is there a way to somehow "steal" it from the newer look of android and implement it in my project?

I would like this:
[image]

Comment: You can use this website to create holo theme in your android app : http://android-holo-colors.com/ .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***You need*** [HoloEverywhere](https://github.com/Prototik/HoloEverywhere).

Althought If your need is only change background of Editext or any views, you should copy them from newer sdk's `sdk/platforms/version/data/res` directory and use them into your project
.